# What UI Frameworks for Angular are out there?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angular-kendo

Other JavaScript frameworks have complex UI widgets such as Treeviews, grids, and charts that include a lot of functionality inside of them.

Since I'm familiar with Kendo, I started using `angular-kendo` but found very little documentation and usage.

What does everyone use for UI frameworks in Angular? I'm looking for one UI framework to use with Angular, not a lot of different libraries and controls patched together.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140875/ui-framework-to-use-with-angular-js)

Comment: you could search for ShadowDOM / WebComponents compatible libraries, as those fit well with AngularJS. Complex UIs like treeviews, are better "offloaded" to Angular directives to make a bridge, but usually those use event delegation to speed things up, and you only "act on Angular" when needed.

Comment: What you describe is the biggest problem of 'HTML5' development. Many of the SO questions on Angular seem to be about making different libraries work together.  For grids, take a look at ngGrid. Other components are available in the UI-Bootstrap library.  I haven't had to look for trees, though.  If you crave an integrated solution with a robust UI library, you may consider the Sencha tools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have used Sencha too, and thats exactly what I am missing - the kendo/sencha type integrated solution. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest and best documented angular widget library in my opinion is [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). But I agree that there is a lack of well documented and well tested libraries out there right now. While Angular is very popular it is also very new so I'm sure we'll see bigger and better libraries emerge as the community matures.

Comment: The initial release of Angular was in 2009; that is ancient in Internet years.

Comment: @JeffryHouser true but if you take a look at something like google trends it implies that almost all of the angular users started using it in the last year: http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#cat=0-5-31&q=angularjs

Comment: I don't question that it has risen in popularity a lot recently.  I just question whether it is "very new".

Comment: The community is very new so that's what matters in the context of community support

Comment: Thanks @rob - accepting your answer as its very useful to my decision making at this point. At this point, rather not have the whole team spend time trying to figure out multiple libraries since this is a very grid/chart/tree intensive app. Hopefully we will have more mature integrated solutions soon :(

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Angular Kendo UI](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/)
, [Angular Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
and [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/).  I have been using all 3 for several months and can say that they are pretty good.  Not without flaws and gaps, like any other frameworks, but very functional.

Comment: Also, could try AngularStrap http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/ over Angular Bootstrap

Comment: @terryt thanks for the suggestion - I shall try AngularUI. Already tried Angular-Kendo, but my issues is that its not as seamless and well documented as plain Kendo is (using jQuery etc).